# Test to see if page loaded with JQuery load()

Tags: jquery, load, preventdefault

I've been using JQuery's `load();` function a bit to load parts of a site's content.

I've been reading that while this may look nice, using `load()` ruins any good hope for SEO, so suggestions have been to keep a real link within the `ahref` link selector I am using, so when Google goes to crawl that link, it will find that content.

Then, I've just been ignoring that action using JQuery's `preventDefault();`.

My question is, say I have something like

```
$('#mylink').click(function(a) {
   a.preventDefault();
   $('myContainer').load('about.php');
});
```

That file, `about.php`, wouldn't normally include a header or footer because I'm placing it within some container already, BUT, can I have a condition or test of sorts on `about.php` to see if it was called using `load();`?  So that if someone were to say visit `www.mysite.com/about.php` it would load the rest of the content in, making it look like a normal page?

Comment: You could have `about.php` always give the full page, and have jQuery parse out only what it needs.  `$('myContainer').load('about.php #myContainer');`  http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Comment: Sure you can, what server side language are you using?

Comment: @RocketHazmat that's a good suggestion, lol.  Felix Kling, PHP.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, FYI, although the answer I marked correctly answers the question, I'm using your idea.  Much more efficient.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my sites, I like to make it easy, so I always have the header/footer added to the page.  When you use jQuery's `.load()`, you can tell it to parse out a certain part of the loaded page.

```
$('myContainer').load('about.php #myContainer');
```

This tells jQuery to load `about.php`, but only append `#myContainer` to the element.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments

Answer (score 2):

Sure, in your PHP file you can detect if the page was requested with ajax or not, and include the header and footer if it was'nt:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
     strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //requested with ajax
}else{
    //not ajax, include more content
}
```

You could just as easily make that a variable and use it to trigger PHP includes in the correct places to include more content etc.

Answer (score 2):

I do this all the time to make it work with pushState(). Put the contents you are trying to load into a subfolder, like pages/whatever.php, then have the normal page contain all the content u want (header, footer, etc) and require pages/whatever.php. For the jQuery .load(), just pull in the pages/ file.

It's somewhat tedious, but SEO-compliant and much more modular.

Comment: great suggestion as well.  I appreciate your feedback.  @RocketHazmat's answer in the comments is a pretty nice solution to this as well, and saves the redundancy of making 2 files.

Comment: agreed, his solution is very clean. the only reason i separate them is because it makes styling a hell of a lot easier, and it also makes it easy to load the same content onto different pages.